# Is Point-to-Point protocol suitable for on-board moving systems (train)

Tags: embedded-linux, at-command, lte, ppp

I am designing an on-board unit system that is going to be implemented in a train. This embedded system runs linux and needs an LTE module to maintain connected.

The LTE module can be used through AT commands or PPP (Point-to-Point Protocol). I would use C language to develop AT commands application.

As a developer, PPP is easier but I guess that I will have more problems with the coverage than with AT commands. So, I would like to know which way would be the best for this environment(train), trying to provide the best coverage possible to the on-board unit.

Any advice or information would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any difference between PPP and AT commands with regards to "coverage". After all, that's the PHYS layer, unaffected by what you put on top of it. With PPP, you get the error detection/correction layer for free. With AT commands, you need to implement it yourself or ignore errors (how'd that work?). Go figure.

Comment: What I wanted to know was that using AT commands could improve PPP's error detection/correction layer. I guess that PPP is not intended to use in moving environments (I do not know) so maybe I could improve it using AT commands.

Comment: You are mixing up things. AT commands allow you talk to your local device and do some  local and remote adjustments. The communications over LTE is going to by IP based anyhow, so you cannot evade that. Use PPP or L2TP and you're going to be fine.

Comment: I thought that using AT commands I could have more information about how the network is or the sockets status. But I guess that PPP will work better than everything I was going to develop.

Comment: Coverage depends on signal strength on your unit and it should be taken care by the LTE module of your unit with appropriate tuning (if required). PPP or L2TP in-turn run over LTE which in-turn shall take care of your mobility concerns.